# Firebase Database get children of specific level android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database structure in Firebase:
[image]

In my app when I launch an activity. I want to get all the `level0Node`'s nodes only once when the activity is started. This I achieve like this:

```
rootNode.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> level0Nodes = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
```

But the problem I am facing is that if any updates occur on the `level1Node`'s, `onDataChanged` is invoked again which I do not want. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a `SingleValueListener`.

Replace your `ValueEventListener` with one, the code would look like this:

```
rootNode.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> level0Nodes = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

For more info refer to the [Official Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)

Answer (score 1):

you have two methods for getting total data in one go from a particular reference.

1. **rootNode.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener**(){}

   // this you are using and according to documentation this is triggered when ever the data is change at this node- rootNode.  if you want to use it only once your can remove  your listner by calling

rootNode.removeEventListener()  method for removing further updates.

2. use **rootNode.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener**() {}

according to documentation this is only triggered once so when ever there is a change in your child this listner will not trigger and your problem will be solve.

plus i just want to suggest you to read full documentation on firebase as your question was very basic.